# How to apply filter when page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Filters have this code:

```css
<li style="float:left; width:70px; padding-left: 10px;"><a href="#none" data-filter=".film"><img src="img/study.png" width="70"></a></li>
<li style="float:left; width:70px; padding-left: 10px;"><a href="#none" data-filter=".music"><img src="img/study.png" width="70"></a></li>
<li style="float:left; width:70px; padding-left: 10px;"><a href="#none" data-filter=".art"><img src="img/study.png" width="70"></a></li>
```

I want to create an autoload for a filter when starting the page.
The main in the filter is:

```
data-filter=".music"
```

But I dont know automatically call this filter when starting the page. How do I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by autoload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on `$(document).ready()`.

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('[data-filter=".music"]').click()
    }
);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsrvd9et/

`[data-filter=".music"]` is a selector that selects an element based on an attribute value. And `document.ready` is an event that runs when the page is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Comment: I have this template: http://pukekodesigns.co.nz/clients/rebound/
I tested your exemple, but failed. :(

Comment: OK, is there a problem?

Comment: @JulioMarcelo if go to the website you have there and run '$('[data-filter=".music"]').click()' in the console. it works fine. It selects the music link and the images rearrange. I don't see that code in the site resources at all.

Comment: @JulioMarcelo Happy to help! Good luck!